# Importing a python module

Tags: python, module

I built a small demo script, which I want to import into another python script. The code is as follows:

```
class count:
def __init__(self):
    
    def students(self,males,females):
        return males + females

    def teachers(self,bsc,nce):
        return bsc - nce

    def cleaners(self,older,younger):
        return older + younger

class salary(count):
def __init__(self):
    
    count.__init__(self)
    
    def teachers_salary(self,teachers,amount):
        return teachers * amount

    def cleaner_salary(self,cleaners,amount):
        return cleaners * amount

    def gardeners_salary(self,gardeners,amount):
        return gardeners * amount
```

I saved this script as `count.py` and I now want to import it into another script, so that I can use its modules. But when I use `from count import salary` and then run the code `salary.teachers(bsc=10,nce=15)`, I get the error message below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-b9aec73e51ba> in <module>
----> 1 print(salary.teachers(bsc=10,nce=15))

TypeError: teachers() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Please, can someone advise me on what I am not doing right? Thanks as always.

Comment: Is there more code other than that? I just get a ```AttributeError: type object 'salary' has no attribute 'teachers'```

Comment: Why are you using classes? All of those methods just look like free functions.

Comment: I know I can write these functions separately, but I am only trying to understand how modules work and how to use them correctly. @ndc85430

Comment: @ClementGenninasca Hi, there isn't more to the code than that.